# Can I reload a table only after a certain action is triggered on a different viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, loading

This is my current situation. I'd like to only reload a table once a user 'sends' a post. What's happening right now, is that everytime the main view controller becomes active, it reloads the information. This causes some problems, as a user loses their place when they return to said main viewcontroller.

To break it down further. I have two main vcs. A main page holding posts, and a 'create posts' page. What I want to do, is reload the main table, once the user hits send on the 'create posts' page.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    skip = 0
self.loadObjects()

}
```

This piece of code currently reloads the information once the main page becomes active and yes, it works but like I mentioned, if a users scrolls down, and moves from the main page, once they return their place is lost.

To reiterate. I'd like to make it so self.loadobjects() is ONLY called once a user hits 'send' on the 'create posts' viewcontroller.

Comment: if (self.isMovingToParentViewController == NO) {  
 } if this is NO then you are responding to a PUSH, else you are arriving from a POP

Comment: this means, place this in your viewWillAppear, if you are coming to the FIRST main view controller from a PUSH then this will activate, if you ARE moving to the FIRST Main view controller from a BACK button press which is a POP then this won't activate .. err, it's the other way around, I can't remember, off the top of my head, but this is the setting

Comment: @Larcerax so basically so override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if (self.isMovingToParentViewController() == false)
        {
            skip = 0
            self.loadObjects()
        }
   
        
    }

Comment: Yes, like that, should with swfit, but check Apple docs to make sure I have the order right, but this is what I do in ObjC

Comment: @Larcerax Hm. I tried this but unfortunately it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard ways to do this: Notifications and reference (or delegate). Since I think notifications are the "right" way for this kind of task I'll show this:

In the action method for your button (the code that is called when the user presses the Send button):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("theyPressedTheButton", object: nil)
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad` method of your View controller that has the table view:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("someMethodinThisClass:"), name: "theyPressedTheButton", object: nil)
```

Then somewhere in the class

```
 fun someMethodinThisClass(notification : NSNotification)
```

In the `deinint` method of the class that has the tableview you need to put this code so you don't leak

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "theyPressedTheButton", object: nil)
```

Finally, in your "someMethod" function you can reload the tableview data or whatever else you want to have happen. If you have the case where the view isn't loaded when the user presses the button, then there is no harm. You will post the notification and no one will listen to it.

[image]

Comment: I added in func someMethodinThisClass(notification : NSNotification)
    {
        self.loadObjects()
    }

Comment: And followed your instructions, but things don't seem to be loading.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in someMethodinThisClass is it being hit?

Comment: No its not. Quite odd.

Comment: So, verify that your string "theyPressedTheButton" matches in both locations and also set a breakpoint inside of the action method in your Send button.

Comment: To clarify, do I put the funcsomemethodinthisclass in the Post View Controller or the Table View Controller?